Jetpack Navigation: Is defining argument on graph still required if not using Safe Args plugin?
Coming from the traditional manual navigation from Fragment to next Activity using startActivity, we also use Intent to pass data/arguments. Now to fully utilize Jetpack Navigation, we are now using the NavController to navigate from Fragment to next Activity with the below code.
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/menu_asset">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_asset"
        android:name="com.sample.app.presentation.ui.main.AssetsFragment"
        android:label="@string/assets"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_assets_list" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_menu_asset_to_asset_detail_activity"
            app:destination="@id/asset_detail_activity" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_news"
        android:name="com.sample.app.presentation.ui.main.NewsFragment"
        android:label="@string/news"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news_list" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_menu_news_to_news_detail_activity"
            app:destination="@id/news_detail_activity" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_videos"
        android:name="com.sample.app.presentation.ui.main.VideosFragment"
        android:label="@string/videos"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_videos_list" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_menu_videos_to_video_player_activity"
            app:destination="@id/video_player_activity" />
    </fragment>

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/asset_detail_activity"
        android:name="com.sample.app.presentation.AssetDetailActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_asset_detail">

        <argument
            android:name="EXTRA_ASSET"
            app:argType="com.sample.app.domain.models.AssetDataDomain" />

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/news_detail_activity"
        android:name="com.sample.app.presentation.NewsDetailActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_news_detail">

        <argument
            android:name="EXTRA_NEWS"
            app:argType="com.sample.app.domain.models.PostDataDomain" />

        <argument
            android:name="EXTRA_NEWS_LIST"
            app:argType="com.sample.app.domain.models.PostDataDomain[]" />

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/video_player_activity"
        android:name="com.sample.app.presentation.VideoPlayerActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_video_player">

        <argument
            android:name="EXTRA_VIDEO"
            app:argType="com.sample.app.domain.models.VideoDataDomain" />

    </activity>

</navigation>

AssetFragment of MainActivity navigating to AssetDetailActivity
findNavController().navigate(
   R.id.action_menu_asset_to_asset_detail_activity,
   bundleOf(AssetDetailActivity.INTENT_ASSET to domain)
)

AssetDetailActivity
 val arg = IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra(intent, key, T::class.java)

We get arguments to destination in the old fashion if not using the Safe Args plugin, and removing the argument tag in NavGraph also works fine. Is it optional to define argument in the graph when not using Safe Args?
